# PHP Looping content of a page, make and keep changes

Tags: php, loops

Database generated page will be saved as static pages but the url's within the page itself needs to be rewritten. The function is **already** made.

-> I got an error : implode(): Invalid arguments passed

Goal : the website will be in 3 languages but they all uses the same page index.php. So that's not good enough for google. So static pages will be generated and each language will have his own folder.

While the page is extracted I'll do some url rewrite within the codes of the extracted content. (No not just an Url rewrite for .htaccess. That's not the point at all.)
The pages will change name completely and becomes a static page.
I hope this is clear enough. Hope someone find a way, I tried so much I have almost lost hope to accomplish this.

```
//At the beginning of the page above the HTML tag. 
//Destination for the page and the new name for the page.

$cachefile = "../".trim($_GET['lang'])."/".trim($_GET['page']).".php";

ob_start();

<html>
<body>
...
</body>
</html>

 // At the end of the page
 $content = ob_get_contents();


// here the loop with my function to find an url

$content = ob_get_contents();

$arrcontent = explode(" ",$content); 

$newcontent="";

foreach($arrcontent as $value){

    $value = replaceurl_newurlmenu($value, $pathwebsite, $pathmenu);

    $newcontent .= array($value);    

}

$content =  implode(" ",$newcontent);



// then write everything to a page at a new destination

$fp = fopen($cachefile, 'w');    
fwrite($fp,  $content);    
fclose($fp);    

ob_end_flush();
```

Comment: You may want to consider using meta data tags for SEO. ie: `Content-Language: en, hi, pa`

Comment: Or a multilingual blog or CMS

Comment: @ user2182349  what fun is it than to have a website if someone else made that ?

Comment: @yardpenalty   I got those meta tags all build in, adaptation for each page as well.

Comment: Actually CMS are simply tools. You have to customize your site and you can accomplish more using tools and still become a great programmer. No reason to re-invent the wheel. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix what you have

```
$arrcontent = explode(" ",$content); 

$newcontent=array();

foreach($arrcontent as $value){

$value = replaceurl_newurlmenu($value, $pathwebsite, $pathmenu);

$newcontent[] = $value;    

}

$content =  implode(" ",$newcontent);
```

But I would consider looking at array_walk method too.

Comment: Hey that works really well. Thanks, I knew it has to do with an array but couldn't figure it out how.   Thanks again.

Comment: Don't forget to mark as answer by clicking on check mark. Glad your issue was resolved.